# am I able to use android serives in the first time I run my application

Tags: android, eclipse, service, startup

I want to get event when I use my program for the firt time so I decided to use this service

```
public class PackageChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    Context context;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
}}
```

and in the mainfest

```
 <receiver android:name=".PackageChangeReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
                <data android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

but this services don't work in the fist time I install my application , how can I make it run in the first time ?or it is not possible to do that ?
I have to update the application from eclipse second time to make this service working , what is the problem.

when does android system make its services available to use , I heart onetime that I should run one of my activity to make the service available ,is it true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting Android 3.1, any app that wishes to receive broadcasts must have had one of its UI components (i.e an Activity) run at least once before Android sends any broadcasts to it. This is done for security reasons, to prevent malicious apps from auto launching.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't really replace a package. It updates your existing install. If you've run anything before the update, then Android will continue to give you broadcasts.